# How to populate a field in MongoDB aggregate $lookup result?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I can't find a solution using other answers on the internet or my attempts. That is why I am creating a new question.

I have 2 collections - **posts**, **users** and I use MongoDB + Mongoose.

How can I use aggregate to have all users that belong to certain post?

I need something like **populate** but I need to use aggregate (I use more complex aggregate, this is just an example)

I have field **likes** which holds all **users** who liked certain post. So **likes.users.user** holds an ID for user who liked.

How can I change this field via aggregate to hold object with **user information** instead of just an ID? See **desired output**, please.

**Before aggregate output:**

```
{
    "_id": "5eb011af5c9246204944156e",
    "title": "My awesome blog post",
    "likes": {
        "count": 3,
        "users": [
            {
                "_id": "5eb011ba5c92462049441570",
                "user": "5e915d5e116d010560470107"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5eb012535c92462049441576",
                "user": "5e915d76116d010560470108"
            },
            {
                "_id": "5eb018d57ae41a2171478ff1",
                "user": "5e915d8b116d010560470109"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Desired output:**

```
{
    "_id": "5eb011af5c9246204944156e",
    "title": "My awesome blog post",
    "likes": {
        "count": 3,
        "users": [
            {
                "_id": "5eb011ba5c92462049441570",
                "user": {
                    "_id": "5e915d5e116d010560470107",
                    "name": "John Doe",
                    "role": "member"
                } 
            }, 
            {
                "_id": "5eb011ba5c92462049441576",
                "user": {
                    "_id": "5e915d5e116d010560470108",
                    "name": "Daniel Grant",
                    "role": "member"
                } 
            },
            {
                "_id": "5eb018d57ae41a2171478ff1",
                "user": {
                    "_id": "5e915d5e116d010560470109",
                    "name": "Tiffany Holland",
                    "role": "administrator"
                } 
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Current bad output:**

```
{
    "_id": "5eb011af5c9246204944156e",
    "title": "My awesome blog post",
    "likes": {
        "count": 3,
        "users": [
            {
                "_id": "5eb011ba5c92462049441570",
                "user": {
                    "_id": "5e915d5e116d010560470107",
                    "name": "John Doe",
                    "role": "member"
                } 
            }, 
            {
                "_id": "5eb011ba5c92462049441576",
                "user": {
                    "_id": "5e915d5e116d010560470107",
                    "name": "John Doe",
                    "role": "member"
                } 
            },
            {
                "_id": "5eb018d57ae41a2171478ff1",
                "user": {
                    "_id": "5e915d5e116d010560470107",
                    "name": "John Doe",
                    "role": "member"
                } 
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

It is basically what I need but it is only one user of 3 and it shows duplicates. Why?

**Aggregate I tried:**

```
const aggregatedData = await Post.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId( id ) } },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "likes.users.user",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "likesUsers"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$likesUsers"
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            "likes.users.user": "$likesUsers",
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "likesUsers": 0,
        }
    }
]);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This aggregation will get the desired result.

```
db.posts.aggregate([
  {
      $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "likes.users.user",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "likesUsers"
      }
  },
  { 
      $addFields: {
          "likes.users": {
              $map: {
                   input: "$likes.users", as: "usr",
                   in: {
                       user: {
                           $arrayElemAt: [ 
                               { $filter: {
                                     input: "$likesUsers", as: "likeUsr",
                                     cond: {
                                         $eq: [ "$$usr.user", "$$likeUsr._id" ]
                                     }
                                }
                            }, 0 ]
                       },
                       _id: "$$usr._id"
                   } 
               }
           }
      }
  },
  {
      $project: { likesUsers: 0 }
  }
] )
```